# lodash find matching keys/nested keys

Tags: javascript, momentjs, lodash

I have a standard object, with nested objects.

I am trying to find all keys that contain 'Gmt' and format the corresponding epoch value via moment.

```
var myObject = {
    "suffix" : "mr",
    "fname" : "jullian",
    "lname" : "exor",
    "dobGmt" : 145754294700000
    "addressLine1" : "flat 8a",
    "street" : "hoxley close",
    "rentStartedGmt" : 145754294700000,
    "deposit" : "50.00",
    "occupation" : "math teacher",
    "profession" : {
         "careerStartedGmt": 1458755224800000,
         "careerEndGmt": 1459854224800000,
     },
    "salary" : 28000,
    "votingDetail" : {
        "location" : "virgina",
        "votedOnGmt": 1874585224800000,
        "votedFor" : "world wildlife foundation"
    }
}
```

I can use standard JS to loop through the keys above (see below), which will find `rentStartedGmt` however will miss `profession.careerStartedGmt`, `profession.careerEndGmt` and `votingDetail.votedOnGmt`

```
var myObjectClone = _.clone(myObject);

for (var key in myObjectClone) {
    if (key.indexOf("Gmt") !== -1) {

        var timeValue = myObjectClone[key];

        timeValue = timeValue.format('DD-MM-YY HH:mm:ss');

    }
}
```

I am using lodash, is there any way i can find all keys that contain 'Gmt', modify the epoch, and return back the object clone.

---

Update: Using recursion:

```
function findGmt(data) {
    for (var key in data) {
        var v = data[key];
        if (key.indexOf("Gmt") !== -1) {


        }

        if(v && typeof v === "object") {
            findGmt(v);
        }
    }
}

findGmt(myObjectClone);
```

Comment: You need recursion. None of lodash methods support recursion. So you  have to write your own recursive function.

Comment: @hindmost - ah i see, thanks for the advice. Have updated with a recursive attempt.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know of a lodash specific method for this...

but here's a recursive function in vanilla js:

```js
var obj = {
  "suffix": "mr",
  "fname": "jullian",
  "lname": "exor",
  "dobGmt": 145754294700000,
  "addressLine1": "flat 8a",
  "street": "hoxley close",
  "rentStartedGmt": 145754294700000,
  "deposit": "50.00",
  "occupation": "math teacher",
  "profession": {
    "careerStartedGmt": 1458755224800000,
    "careerEndGmt": 1459854224800000,
  },
  "salary": 28000,
  "votingDetail": {
    "location": "virgina",
    "votedOnGmt": 1874585224800000,
    "votedFor": "world wildlife foundation"
  }
}


function flatK(o) {
  return Object.keys(o).reduce(function(ac, x) {
    if (typeof o[x] === 'object')
      ac.push(flatK(o[x]).join());
    else
      ac.push(x);
    return ac
  }, [])
}

console.log(flatK(obj))
```

then you can filter the output looking for 'GMT' in the key (but I'll let you do that )

Comment: thanks for this! is this any better/more efficient than my updated recursive attempt?

Comment: even if your function doesn't return anything I can see the attempt of filtering while looping... usually it's preferred to keep functions as neutral as possible so you can reuse them, but this depends on situation.